# If I put in a limit order for the same price and size as someone else, which order goes through?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I put a limit buy order for 1000 shares at $1.26, and another investor has also put a limit buy order in for the same amount and volume. If someone sells 1000 shares at $1.26, which one of us gets the shares?

Comment: Note that the answers below assume you have direct access to an exchange; most individual investors do not.  If you place your order through a retail broker, it's unlikely for your actual order to ever hit a real exchange.  Instead your retail broker will (a) match your order against another of its clients, (b) place a better order than the one you wanted (at sub-penny prices that are only available to retail companies!) and then pocket the difference, or (c) engage in any number of other shenanigans.  Bottom line: **retail investors' orders almost never hit the actual stock exchanges.**

Answer (score 13):

The one whose order gets to the exchange first. The exchange receives the orders and arranges them in First-In-First-Out order, by which they're then executed. At some point it is synchronized and put into a list. Whoever gets to that point first - gets the deal.

Answer (score 5):

While littleadv's answer is true for many exchanges (in particular the stock market, it's called FIFO matching) you should also know that some markets trade **pro rata**.  That is, for a match at some price level everyone at that level gets a chunk of the deal proportional to their input (i.e. order size).

E.g. match for quantity `X` at a price level and passive side orders `y1`, `y2`; the order `y1` would get `y1 / (y1 + y2)` of `X` and `y2` would get `y2 / (y1 + y2)`  (for `X = min(X, y1 + y2)`).